# How to add multiple of the same provider

Tags: gnome, 17.10, online-accounts

I'm happy with the "Online Accounts" of Ubuntu 17.10; having all accounts I need calendar/reminder data from in one place. But unfortunately, I have multiple accounts for, for example, Microsoft. But, I can't seem to add more than one account to my online accounts. I can add an account, no problem, but when I try to add another one, it pops up a new window, but it shows the "approval" part of the account I already added.

Is there a solution or workaround to add more than one online accounts of the same provider?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After adding an account click on that provider again, and you'll see an option to 'Use Another Account'

But I think it's only possible with Google.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I believe this is only for Google. The Microsoft category doesn't have that question.